# How to use the optimizer_search_depth in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Guys I've googled everyting on examples on how to use this feature in mysql. But no luck.

Can i use it like this?

```
select optimizer_search_depth = 7 from some table
```

Please give me example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of many system variables that you can set either by using the SET command or by defining values in the config file.

Please see  [server system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html) in the MySQL manual.

You can set it for example with

```
SET optimizer_search_depth = <new value>;
```

you can fetch the current value with

```
show variables like "optimizer%";
```